# How to get jXDatePicker1 value using mouseclick? (Java)

Tags: java, swing

```
 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    bidtxt.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
    booktxt.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
    authortxt.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 2).toString());
    isbntxt.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 3).toString());

    publishertxt.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 4).toString());


    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    jXDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
    DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String Dob  = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate()).toString();


    String d =(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 5).toString());
    Date date;

    try {

        date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(d);
        jXDatePicker1.setDate(date);

     } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Member.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

 }
```

I'm trying to get values displayed on my JTable, which when I click the values go into the right text fields. All the other fields but the jxdatepicker does not go into the field.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can help?

Comment: do you want to set the value or get the value from the datepicker? if you want to get the value, where you want to store it?